# WinForms Queue GUI Grid Layout

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been working on an appeals management system where a user inputs appeals into a windows form and it is automatically assigned to an advisor.  On the main page, after signing in, there is a "queue" like box (a listbox) which displays the appeals that are active and includes the appeal date, user id, and name of the person is submitted an appeal.  Currently this layout works because the date is always 10 characters and the user id is always 7 characters (which is why I leave the name for last).  Eventually, I want to add more data, which means I need a better way of displaying that data.  I found the following image:

[image]

I am left wondering how something like this was accomplished.  Is this just a DataGridView object, or something else altogether?  If it is that, is there a way I can control the visuals of that objects? (Highlight color, grid line thickness, stuff like that)

(My data is stored in an SQL database, if that helps)

Comment: Yes you should try using DataGridView

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off-topic here.

Comment: Are you sure the picture is showing a `winforms` `Form`? It is difficult to tell, but it looks like a WPF form. Can you clarify? What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnG - The OP says he "found" the image. It could be from anywhere.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realize this was off-topic for this location.  I found the image on fiverr for someone offering programming services.  I might take a look into both WPF and datagridview and see which will suit my needs most.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an ObjectListView

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

It is an enhanced listview, designed for displaying data from Objects in a simple easy way with lots of features.  I use it all the time.

It also has a Databound version, and treeview version, all with similar features.

The examples on the home page are all very colourful, but simpler views are the default, such as this from one of my apps.

[image: OLV Image]

In includes grouping, sorting, filtering, out of the box.  And allows you to do much more.

It works differently to the normal listview, in that you link a collection of objects to the ObjectListView via the `SetObjects` command and don't add item individually.

Comment: I'll take a look into this as well, thank you very much!